# Display countdown in user's local time

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I want to implement a simple javascript countdown that always counts down to the user's local next Friday, 15:00. I currently use the following code, but I believe that it only displays the countdown to next Friday, 15:00 UTC. Any help would really be appreciated!!

```js
var curday;
var secTime;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var dy = 5; //Sunday through Saturday, 0 to 6
  var countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 15, 0, 0);

  var curtime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
  var atime = countertime.getTime(); //countdown time
  var diff = parseInt((atime - curtime) / 1000);
  if (diff > 0) {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay()
  } else {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() - 1
  } //after countdown time
  if (curday < 0) {
    curday += 7;
  } //already after countdown time, switch to next week
  if (diff <= 0) {
    diff += (86400 * 7)
  }
  startTimer(diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
  secTime = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
  tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
  var secs = secTime;
  if (secs > 0) {
    secTime--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker);
    getSeconds(); //start over
  }

  var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
  secs %= 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;

  //update the time display
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = curday;
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
}

function starter() {
  getSeconds();
}
```

Comment: In `startTimer`, use this function ref instead... `ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript dates are inherently UTC, however the various non–UTC *get* and *set* methods all work on local dates and times based on the host system clock and daylight saving settings.

So if you're not using UTC methods, everything in the OP is "local" by default. The following is a simplistic implementation of your "time until next Friday at 15:00" all as local values:

```js
function timeUntil() {
  let now = new Date();
  // Create date for 15:00 on coming Friday 
  let friday = new Date(now);
  friday.setHours(15,0,0,0);
  let dayNum = friday.getDay();
  friday.setDate(friday.getDate() + 5 - (dayNum < 6? dayNum : 5 - dayNum));
  // If today is Friday and after 15:00, set to next Friday
  if (dayNum == 5 && friday < now) {
    friday.setDate(friday.getDate() + 7);
  }
  
  // Time remaining
  let diff = friday - now;
  let days = diff / 8.64e7 |0;
  let hrs  = (diff % 8.64e7) / 3.6e6 | 0; 
  let mins = (diff % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0; 
  let secs = (diff % 6e4) / 1e3 | 0; 

  // Display result
  document.getElementById('days').textContent = days;
  document.getElementById('hrs').textContent = hrs;
  document.getElementById('mins').textContent = mins;
  document.getElementById('secs').textContent = secs;
  document.getElementById('fullDate').textContent = friday.toLocaleString();
}

setInterval(timeUntil, 1000);
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Days<th>Hrs<th>Mins<th>Secs
  <tr><td id="days"><td id="hrs"><td id="mins"><td id="secs">
  <tr><td id="fullDate" colspan="4">
</table>
```

Note that *setInterval* isn't a good way to run a timer over a long period as it drifts (it doesn't run at *exactly* the specified interval). The overall time will be OK, it will just seem to skip from time to time and drift within a second with respect to the system displayed clock.

Better to use sequential calls *setTimeout*, calculating the time until just after the next full second each time so it closely matches the system clock's tick.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!!